# Expanding results from a dynamic array in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel spreadsheet in Office365 that I'm using a FILTER() dynamic arrays in to populate a parent/child table from external data. It provides me with the following information (element and phase):

```
element1    A
element2    ABC
element3    BC
```

For presentation and further analysis, I would like the information to be expanded out into the following format:

```
element1    A
element2    A
element2    B
element2    C
element3    B
element3    C
```

Due to the irregularity of the data as far as how many parent/children pairs there will be, I want to stick entirely to dynamic arrays (instead of dragging a formula to the bottom of a sheet and using a blanking IF scheme when I'm out of matches).

I had something working that required generating a (non-dynamic) sum of lengths of phases above a given point, then giving each row the value of the first nearest greater element, but after an Excel crash I can't get back there to provide an example.  Is what I'm after possible or am I looking at this the wrong way?

EDIT:
`={INDEX(dynamicRangeCell#,MATCH(TRUE,ABClengthCumulativeSumRange>ROW(),0))}` is the non-dynamic approach, but I could not get it to work with a dynamic approach

Comment: That is the way the data is stored in the source table?  In other words, the FILTER is not doing any CONCAT or TEXTJOIN?  Just making sure it would not be easier to go back to the base data instead of the output of the FILTER.

Comment: @ScottCraner the source table is just
`elementName    ABC`
with any combination of ABC. it represents one physical bundle of 3 components, basically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is no easy task to do with formula:

```
=LET(
    rng,C1#,
    ch,INDEX(rng,0,2),
    pa,INDEX(rng,0,1),
    HSTACK(
         INDEX(pa,MATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(LEN(ch)),,0),VSTACK(0,SCAN(0,LEN(ch),LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))))),
         LET(n,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,BYROW(ch,LAMBDA(c,IFERROR(REDUCE(c,SEQUENCE(,LEN(c)-1,LEN(c),-1),LAMBDA(a,b,REPLACE(a,b,0,"|"))),c)))),"|",";")),FILTER(n,NOT(ISERROR(n))))))
```

It basically creates two arrays the list of the fist column expanded by the count of letters in column 2 with the column 2 expanded by the letter.

The first is just a matter of creating a running sum of the length of the string in the second column and using match.  we need to append `0` to the beginning of that running sum array to get the correct return from the match.

The second we create text string with `|` between each letter in the cell and `;` between the cells.  Then we use TEXTSPLIT to split the string into its own array and then use TOCOL to stack it into one column.

Then we use HSTACK to line them up nice and pretty.

[image]

Comment: ahhhhhhh I was thinking that a LAMBDA function that acts on each row might be needed after looking into what's in the pipeline.  I don't have access to these for whatever reason (maybe company IT is on an older release?), but this uses every new thing under the sun. I'll give it an answer credit because I don't really feasibly see a way to do this without some of the new stuff to iterate

really cool effort, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have some of the newer O365 functions, perhaps this will work for you:

`=LET(α,INDEX(C1#,,1),β,INDEX(C1#,,2),γ,SEQUENCE(ROWS(β)),δ,LEN(β),ε,SEQUENCE(SUM(δ)),CHOOSE({1,2},XLOOKUP(ε,MMULT(N(γ>=TRANSPOSE(γ)),δ),α,,1),MID(CONCAT(β),ε,1)))`

which, again, assumes that your spilled range is referenced by `C1#`.