# Expanding results from a dynamic array in Excel 2

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a problem that I am trying to solve which is similar to one posted here - [Expanding results from a dynamic array in Excel](https://superuser.com/questions/1740382/expanding-results-from-a-dynamic-array-in-excel).

My array is two columns with the first column being a date and the second column is text of a string with text which can be delimited by ",".

| Date | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 12/2023 | apple, orange, banana |
| 01/2024 | grapes, watermelon |
| 01/2024 | peach, mandarin, apricot, melon |

| Date | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 12/2023 | apple |
| 12/2023 | orange |
| 12/2023 | banana |
| 01/2024 | grapes |
| 01/2024 | watermelon |
| 01/2024 | peach |
| 01/2024 | mandarin |
| 01/2024 | apricot |
| 01/2024 | melon |

I have been trying to modify the formula from the link above with with no success. Any help to modify the formula to arrive at the intended results above is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
=LET(
    rng,C1#,
    ch,INDEX(rng,0,2),
    pa,INDEX(rng,0,1),
    HSTACK(
         INDEX(pa,MATCH(SEQUENCE(SUM(LEN(ch)),,0),VSTACK(0,SCAN(0,LEN(ch),LAMBDA(a,b,a+b))))),
         LET(n,TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(";",,BYROW(ch,LAMBDA(c,IFERROR(REDUCE(c,SEQUENCE(,LEN(c)-1,LEN(c),-1),LAMBDA(a,b,REPLACE(a,b,0,"|"))),c)))),"|",";")),FILTER(n,NOT(ISERROR(n))))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways outlined using `Excel Formulas` :

Using `LAMBDA()` helper function called `REDUCE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=REDUCE(A1:B1,SEQUENCE(ROWS(A2:B4)),LAMBDA(φ,δ,
 VSTACK(φ,IF({1,0},INDEX(A2:B4,δ,0),TEXTSPLIT(INDEX(A2:B4,δ,2),,", ",1)))))
```

---

Using without `LAMBDA()` helper functions.

```
=LET(
     _Data, A1:B4,
     _Headers, TAKE(_Data,1),
     _DataBody, DROP(_Data,1),
     _Dates, TAKE(_DataBody,,1),
     _Descriptions, TAKE(_DataBody,,-1),
     _DelimCount, MAX(LEN(_Descriptions)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(_Descriptions,",",))+1),
     _DescTransformed, TRIM(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER(","&_Descriptions,",",SEQUENCE(,_DelimCount)),", ")),
     _Merge, HSTACK(INDEX(_Dates,INT(SEQUENCE(ROWS(_DataBody)*_DelimCount,,,1/_DelimCount))),TOCOL(_DescTransformed)),
     VSTACK(_Headers, FILTER(_Merge,1-ISERROR(TAKE(_Merge,,-1)))))
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Although the formula is complicated, the process is fairly simple in Power Query with just a few steps.

PQ is available in Windows Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365 (Windows or Mac)

To use Power Query

- Select some cell in your Data Table
- `Data => Get&Transform => from Table/Range`
- When the PQ Editor opens: `Home => Advanced Editor`
- Make note of the Table **Name** in Line 2
- Paste the M Code below in place of what you see
- Change the Table name in line 2 back to what was generated originally.
- Read the comments and explore the `Applied Steps` to understand the algorithm

```
let

//Change next line to reflect actual data source
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Date", type date}, {"Description", type text}}),

//Transform Description into a list of individual items
    #"Description List" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{
        {"Description", (c)=>List.Transform(Text.Split(c,","), each Text.Trim(_)), type {text}}}),

//expand the description list
    #"Expanded Description" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Description List", "Description")
in
    #"Expanded Description"
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your response. I forgot to mention that I do not want to use Power Query as other people will be adding data to the two columns and I require the formula to update automatically.

Comment: All you would need to do is refresh the query to update the output.

Comment: Using `Power Query` is **correct**, as proposed by @RonRosenfeld Sir. Personally, I would have used it and if there was no solution posted then I would have posted both ways, however **PQ** because in such scenarios it is **effortless and time saving, and also expands automatically by one single refresh, one time approach, takes less than a few.** However, these days modern excel formulas do the same job, but my bet is on `Power Query` **(It doesn't fails me with larger amount datas, where as formulas did)** . Follow as suggested though i have posted a solution just as an alternative.